# Weierstrass elliptic function for quaternions?

Tags: quaternions, periodic-functions, rational-functions

What if we generalize and modify the Weierstrass elliptic function for quaternions ?

So our function could have $2,3$ or $4$ periods.

How would that theory be like ?

Is matrix representation the key here ?

Noticed I picked quaternions because they have no nonzero zero-divisors.

Comment: For possible resources see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372677/quaternionic-and-octonionic-analogues-of-the-basel-problem and the papers cited there.  The Amir-Khosravi paper cited there, "Period Relations for Quaternionic Elliptic Functions," is on the Arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06140 (see e.g. section 3, entitled "Elliptic Functions associated with Lattices")